# How do I get Spring's Data Rest Repository to retrieve data by its name instead of its id

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-rest

I am using Spring Data's Rest Repositories from spring-boot-starter-data-rest, with Couchbase being used as the underlining DBMS.

My Pojo for the object is setup as so.

```
@Document
public class Item{

@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = UNIQUE)
private String id;

@NotNull
private String name;

//other items and getters and setters here
}
```

And say the Item has an id of "xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx" and name of "testItem".
Problem is, that when I want to access the item, I need to be accessible by `/items/testItem`, but instead it is accessible by `/items/xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx`.

How do I get use its name instead of its generated id, to get the data.

Answer (score 1):

I found out the answer to my own question.

I just need to override the config for the EntityLookup.

```
@Component
public class SpringDataRestCustomization extends RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {

    config.withEntityLookup().forRepository(UserRepository.class).
    withIdMapping(User::getUsername).
    withLookup(UserRepository::findByUsername);
    }
}
```

Found the info here, though the method name changed slightly.
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/rest/uri-customization

Answer (score -1):

If you want query the item by name and want it perform as querying by id,you should make sure the name is unique too.You cant identify a explicit object by name if all objects have a same name,right?

With jpa you could do it like:

```
@NotNull
@Column(name="name",nullable=false,unique=true)
private String name;
```

Comment: That's true, but that doesn't that answer the question. Also, I am using Couchbase database, JPA is not used here.